# How to use objects (like entry) in Xamarin.form in private void?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I want to use the button to add entry text to the editor but I get an error!
Here is my code:

```
public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var InputOrdersEntry = new Entry
            {
                FontSize = 10,
                Placeholder = "Enter Your order",
                PlaceholderColor = Color.Gray,
                TextColor = Color.White,
                BackgroundColor = Color.DarkGray,
                MaxLength = 1000,
                Keyboard = Keyboard.Text,
                IsSpellCheckEnabled = false,
                IsTextPredictionEnabled = false
            };
            Button EnterTextToEditorButton = new Button
            {
                FontSize = 10,
                Text = "Enter",
            };
            var LogsEditor = new Editor
            {
                FontSize = 10,
                TextColor = Color.White,
                BackgroundColor = Color.DarkGray,
                MaxLength = 100000,
                IsSpellCheckEnabled = false,
                IsTextPredictionEnabled = false,
                IsReadOnly = true,
            };
        }
        private void EnterTextToEditorButton (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LogsEditor.Text += InputOrdersEntry.Text;
        }
```

And this is Errors:
Error   CS0103  The name 'LogsEditor' does not exist in the current context
Error   CS0103  The name 'InputOrdersEntry' does not exist in the current context

What should I do to fix this errors and do my job too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should declare the `LogsEditor/InputOrdersEntry` at the class level so that they can be accessed in whole class. If you declared them in one method, it can only be accessed in that method:

The complete code here:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    //declaring here as a class level variable
    public Editor LogsEditor;
    public Entry InputOrdersEntry;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        InputOrdersEntry = new Entry
        {
            FontSize = 10,
            Placeholder = "Enter Your order",
            PlaceholderColor = Color.Gray,
            TextColor = Color.White,
            BackgroundColor = Color.DarkGray,
            MaxLength = 1000,
            Keyboard = Keyboard.Text,
            IsSpellCheckEnabled = false,
            IsTextPredictionEnabled = false
        };
        Button EnterTextToEditorButton = new Button
        {
            FontSize = 10,
            Text = "Enter",
        };
        LogsEditor = new Editor
        {
            FontSize = 10,
            TextColor = Color.White,
            BackgroundColor = Color.DarkGray,
            MaxLength = 100000,
            IsSpellCheckEnabled = false,
            IsTextPredictionEnabled = false,
            IsReadOnly = true,
        };
    }
    private void EnterTextToEditorButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LogsEditor.Text += InputOrdersEntry.Text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are declaring `LogsEditor` as a **local** variable inside of your constructor.

```
var LogsEditor = new Editor
```

This means that it will only be visible to code inside of the constructor.  This is a basic [C# scoping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/csharp-code-blocks/) issue, not anything specific to Xamarin

if you want to access this variable elsewhere in your class, declare it as a **class level** variable instead

```
// declare inside of the class, but outside of any specific method
Editor LogsEditor;

public MainPage()
{
  ...

  LogsEditor = new Editor...
```

Comment: I knew but I don't how to do this. Can you explain more please? Thanks

Comment: I already posted an example of the 2 specific lines you need too change to fix your code, and I linked to docs on C# scoping.  What else do you need?

Comment: It was completely clear and I was mistaking. Thanks for your help.